# Why doesn't my code display an image in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem with my program.

```
package game;

    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

    public class deck {

     private Card deckOfCards[];
     private final int number_cards = 52;
     private Random various;
     private int currentCard;
     private int actualCard;
     public ImageIcon CardImage;

     public deck() {
      int value[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11 };

      ImageIcon[] image = {
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon("/root/Desktop/as.jpg"),
      };

      currentCard = 0;
      deckOfCards = new Card[number_cards];
      various = new Random();

      for (int count = 0; count < deckOfCards.length; count++) {
       deckOfCards[count] = new Card(Rank.values()[count % 13].toString(),Suit.values()[count / 13].toString(), value[count % 13], image[count % 13]);
      }
     }

     public void shuffle() {
      currentCard = 0;
      for (int first = 0; first < deckOfCards.length; first++) {
       int second = various.nextInt(number_cards);
       Card temp = deckOfCards[first];
       deckOfCards[first] = deckOfCards[second];
       deckOfCards[second] = temp;
      }
     }

     public Card giveCard() {
      if (currentCard < deckOfCards.length)
       return deckOfCards[currentCard++];
      else
       System.out.println("No more Cards.");
      return null;
     }

     public int totalValue() {
      int cardValue = (deckOfCards[actualCard].toInt());
      return cardValue;
     }

     public ImageIcon getImage() {
      return CardImage;
     }
    }

    package game;

    import java.awt.Image;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

    public class Card {
     private final String faceCard;
     private final String suit;
     private final int number;
     public ImageIcon image;

     Card(String faceCard, String suit, int number_, ImageIcon image) {
      this.faceCard = faceCard;
      this.suit = suit;
      this.number = number_;
      this.image = image;
     }

     public String toString() {
      return faceCard + " of " + suit + "\n" + "Value of card: " + number;
     }

     public int toInt() {
      return number;
     }

     public void setImage(ImageIcon image) {
      this.image = image;
     }

     public ImageIcon getImage() {
      return image;
     }
    }

//swing part
     ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(myDeckOfCards.getImage());

  panel2.add(lab1);
  panel2.add(new JLabel(pic));
  panel2.add(card1);
  panel2.add(pn1);
  panel2.add(btn1);
```

Comment: are you running app from jar ?

Comment: What line does the exception occur on?

Comment: `/root/Desktop/as.jpg` doesn't seems to be an absolute path

Comment: Several things are wrong with the code that you posted. Can you ensure that you post working code. image is an array yet in the setImage() method you are assigning it to a String, missing close brace and so on.

Comment: yes is an error, must be : public void setImage(ImageIcon[] image )

Comment: You've still not provided enough code, we need to see what type myDeckOfCards is and where it's initialised. Either way, you're getting the error most likely because it's null. Do System.out.println(myDeckOfCards) right before the statement that causes the exception if you want to check.

Comment: but my problem at the moment is with the constructors, myDeckOfCards works, and i know because i have this line in the same script:   pn1.setText("Value of card: " + Integer.toString(myDeckOfCards.totalValue()));      ::: this line show the value of each card in swing

Comment: What constructor though? You've only provided one there (for Card) and I can't see how that can throw an NPE under any circumstances.

Comment: the problem is in this lines: public ImageIcon ImageIcon() {
    return image;
}

Comment: @fel in the code above, the method ImageIcon ImageIcon() {} is not located inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException means that something is not initialized. You are referring to something that does not exist. Check The stack-trace. Usually there is a line number on which the exception was thrown. That might give you some hints.

Comment: the problem is that String image must be: public void setImage(ImageIcon[] image )

Comment: Can you post the whole class? And possibly the stack trace?

Comment: i edited my code with corrections, so at the moment i don't have any output. please see again the code above

Comment: if the Exception is thrown here : 
ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(myDeckOfCards.getImage()); 
This means that myDeckOfCards is not initialized.
Also the code you posted is not compilable. Does it compile on your machine?

Comment: the eclipse says that the error is : The constructor ImageIcon(ImageIcon[]) is undefined, so i add to my code the .java with constructors. Thanks for your help

Comment: Full Source now in the post please

Comment: tried to import the source into eclipse, it does not compile. Can you upload somewhere the zipped version of your project?

Comment: sorry for the delay, solved with myDeckOfCard.giveCardPlayer1().getImages(), thanls for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get the image from myDeckOfCards, when it doesn't exist. Do you have an instance of myDeckOfCards declared and initialized?

Comment: yes i have, is my deck of cards, please see gain the code above with corrections

Comment: Sorry, I still dont see the full code. In the 2nd part, I suggest changing name of the method to getImageIcon() and putting the method inside the braces for the class Card, for a start.

Comment: Full Source now in the post please